# Lifetime of BroadcastReceiver with regard to Android O changes

Tags: android, android-intent, android-broadcastreceiver, android-8.0-oreo

If I declare a `BroadcastReceiver` via the mainfest file for a system broadcast (let's say for example `ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED`) the the system will call it every time the specific broadcast is send so the lifetime of the BroadcastReceiver is unrestricted.

But there are also broadcasts which can not be registered via the manifest file. For these broadcasts we have to call `context.registerReceiver` with a corresponding `IntentFilter`.  Let's say I create a BroadcastReceiver for `BOOT_COMPLETED` and call `context.registerReceiver` from it and never call `unregisterReceiver` does this receiver also lives forever (until the phone is rebooted)?

> Apps that target Android O can no longer register broadcast receivers for implicit broadcasts in their manifest. An implicit broadcast is a broadcast that does not target that app specifically.

If my conjecture from above is right this would be an easy workaround for the system change (of course you shouldn't do it this way but it would be possible). So does a `BroadcastReceiver` which is registered after a `BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast have the same lifetime (stays until the next reboot) as a BroadcastReceiver which is automatically registered via the manifest?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Let's say I create a `BroadcastReceiver` for `BOOT_COMPLETED` and call `context.registerReceiver` from it and never call `unregisterReceiver` does this receiver also lives forever (until the phone is rebooted)?

First, `BOOT_COMPLETED` is [one of those actions](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/background-broadcasts.html), that still will behave like they were before, meaning restriction introduced in "O" do not concern to that action.

As soon as the process of your app is killed by the system or  as soon as system clears your app's memory (as a result of low-memory of device), your broadcast registration will be lost. Otherwise I cannot see how this limitation will result in a better battery experience.

> So does a `BroadcastReceiver` which is registered after a `BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast have the same lifetime (stays until the next reboot) as a `BroadcastReceiver` which is automatically registered via the manifest?

If above mentioned cases are not met, i.e. the process of your app stays alive and app is not cleared from memory because of memory shortage - then yes. Once entered into [cached state](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/processes/process-lifecycle.html) (the state with no active Android component) the registration will be lost again.

This [short video by Nasir Khan](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=63pKwVE4Uog) will be helpful.

Comment: Please, where is the google documentation for automatically calling unregisterReceiver if the app didn't call it after calling registerReceiver ?

Comment: @user1510006, couldn't find that point in docs, but as Mr. Khan says: `And you can still register to receive implicit broadcasts while your app is active.` Which I understand as you'll no longer receive the broadcast while app is in cached state.